# What software would you recommend for an Intranet Portal/Forum?

Tags: documentation, forum, portal, intranet

In search of software to implement a Portal for my area (OS Image Deployment) were I can publish Image Releases, Documentation and an area to offer support (forum). The plan it eliminate all email/phone interaction and point all of my users to the portal site. Active Directory Authentication would be a plus but not necessary.

I tried Drupal with the Forum plug-in, but I think I need a more on the Forum side.

I'm currently looking at:

- Wordpress + bbPress
- myBB which includes a portal
- Wrodpress + phpBB

I'm also considering DocuWiki for the documentation (and possibly for announcements on the front-page)

What software would you recommend and do you think Wordpress pages would be enough for creating documentation?

BTW, this project is pretty much me trying to improve my workflow and interaction with my internal users which means I have a budget of $0

Comment: [Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/) is fairly common, but not free.  [$10 for 10 users, all proceeds go to charity](http://www.atlassian.com/starter/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an [enterprise class portal](http://www.liferay.com/products/liferay-portal), I'd recommend [Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/).

> Liferay Portal is an enterprise web
>   platform for building business
>   solutions that deliver immediate
>   results and long-term value. Get the
>   benefits of packaged applications and
>   an enterprise application framework in
>   a single solution.

Comment: Wow, Liferay looks great. The Wiki, Message Boards, Announcements and Calendar features look like they would cover all of my needs.

Which bundle would you recommend: Tomcat, Glashfish, JBoss, Geronimo...

Comment: I've used it with Tomcat + MySQL. Tomcat is pretty simple to work with.

Comment: Think I'm going with Liferay. It has all of the features I need in one package and should make it simpler for my other team members to help out with the upkeep.

Comment: You won't be dissapointed. It's rock solid and easy to get going...

Answer (score 0):

I would choose wiki + forum.

Reason for wiki is:
Keeping the work to edit the documentation to a minimum, while still having a system that can host many pages easly.

Regarding what forum/wiki to choose i would take the following into consideration
1) Bugdet - If you can spend some money i would buy one of the big once like [VB](http://www.vbulletin.com/).
2) What your current enviroment runs on, if you have windows servers and mostly MS SQL servers i would choose one that runs on this.

As for wiki software if you run a windows enviroment, look at [ScrewWiki](http://www.screwturn.eu/) both run on windows servers fine and has plugin support for AD integration.

Comment: ScrewWiki looks good I'll give it a test run. As for budget it's pretty much $0 and server deployment I have access to both Linux and Windows Servers.

Comment: I use ScrewWiki and works good, for forum i would either go with YAF or phpbb. 
But remember that "free" can often mean more work.

Comment: Unfortunately our budget is pretty tight and my project would be at the bottom of the barrel.

Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I like [ikiwiki](http://ikiwiki.info/) for its design. It's a "wiki compiler" which can use popular distributed version control systems as the backend.

So, it's nice for maintaining documentation, and for sites that don't really need to serve dynamic content intensively, which is often the case for intranet community sites.

Running it is simple. A webserver serving an ikiwiki site is a quite simple thing since ikiwiki compiles into static content: so, little effort in administrating it, easy mirroring, or easy moving of the site to another server (+ easy offline editing of the content due to the use of a VCS backend).

It's [used](http://ikiwiki.info/ikiwikiusers/) on the sites of a few well-known software projects, for example, GNU Hurd, DragonFly BSD, xcb.freedesktop.org and more (see http://ikiwiki.info/ikiwikiusers/).

Answer (score 0):

you can directly access and integrate the local workstation's documents/programs with a custom web interface using [intralaunch](http://www.particlesoftware.com) too.  pretty cool stuff.